# Can I say this is a limit cycle?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, dynamical-systems

I have the folowing system of diferential equations in hands,

$$
\frac{dx}{d\lambda} = \frac{d\theta (\lambda)}{d\lambda} \left[ - y + \frac{dr}{d\lambda}\frac{d\lambda}{d\theta}\frac{x}{r}\right] \,\, ,\\
\frac{dy}{d\lambda} = \frac{d\theta (\lambda)}{d\lambda} \left[  x + \frac{dr}{d\lambda}\frac{d\lambda}{d\theta}\frac{y}{r}\right] \,\, ,
$$

where,

$$
\frac{d\theta}{d\lambda} = \frac{L}{r^{2}} \qquad L \in \mathbb{R}^{+} \,\, ,\\
\frac{dr}{d\lambda} = \pm \sqrt{E^{2} - \left(1-\frac{2M}{r}\right)\frac{L^{2}}{r^{2}}} \qquad E \in \mathbb{R}, \  M > 0 \,\, .\\
r^{2} = x^{2} + y^{2} \,\, .
$$

Which give me the following plot when I take $\dot{r} > 0$:

[image: State space of the system.]

And give me the following system when I take $\dot{r} < 0$:

[image: State space of the system of differential equations.]

The black line is the region with $r = 3$. The solutions of this system tends asymptotically to the circle $r = 3$ from bellow when $\dot{r} < 0$ and move away from the circle from above, and vice versa when $\dot{r} > 0$.

The parameters I used in the above were $M=1$, $E^2=\frac{25}{27}$, and $L=5$. Can I say that the circle $r = 3$ is a limit cycle?

Comment: Would you mind giving us the differential equation(s) leading to this?  There is no way to know from a *picture* if what *looks* like a closed obit is indeed a closed orbit, though I admit that pictures can be suggestive and helpful.  So, your equations if you please?  Thanks.

Comment: If you give the equations, then there would be a basis for explaining my previous comment further.  Thanks again.

Comment: I've added the differential equations, I'm not sure if it will be enlightening, they are quite complex equations.

Comment: The equations you gave yield nondecreasing functions $r$, thus **not** the diagram you posted. Anyway, to check that the circle $r=3$ is a limit cycle, simply show that $r'<0$ if $r>3$ and $r'>0$ if $r<3$, and you are done.

Comment: @Did: *simply show that […]* – That’s what you need to show that it’s a *stable* limit cycle. This would be overkill in this case and also probably fail since at least the limit cycle depicted in the state-space portrait is not stable.

Comment: I just wonder from what physics problem your system comes from. Because that's at least the third question on MSE about it that I remember :)

Comment: I just was not convinced that that region was not a limit cycle.

Comment: It works both ways. Is the $\pm$ sign meant to be taken for $\frac{dr}{d\theta}$  positive inside the limit circle $r=3$ and negative outside?. If so, it is a limit cycle where either flow goes to the same asymptote ciircle..However  the field traced in the sketch has incorrect flow direction inside the circle, without a non-zero asymptotic limit radius, so it is not a limit cycle as shown..

Comment: Downvoted because Herr Schrödinger is not responding to the comments which claim that the picture is not corresponding to the given ODE.

Comment: @MrYouMath Sorry for the delay, The plot I've posted is exactly the plot of the system, Should I post the code I used to generate the plot?

Comment: You should check if there is some inconsistency in your equations or your code for plotting. Please edit your question such that I can remove my downvote.

Comment: @Narasimham The $\pm$ can be taken in both ways, positive inside and out, negative inside and out, positive inside and negative out and vice-versa... All these possibilities make physical sense... The case I've ploted is just an special case where is positive everywhere.

Comment: Why are we left in the dark, hazarding guesses about what the question really is? The addition of the $\pm$ symbol is particularly egregious in this context. Is it $+$ or is it $-$, once again we should not have to guess.

Comment: @Did, the differential equation is defined as $\dot{r}^{2} = E^{2}-(1-2M/r)L^{2}/r^{2}$. There are actually two systems, one for $+$ and one for $-$.

Comment: *There are at least 4, actually*... But more importantly, why are we in the rather odd position of still having to discuss this, 22 hours after comments asking you for explanations and 20 hours after you accepted an answer?

Comment: May be the interest it created lingers on after acceptance. I myself thought it was a sort of gravitational model for Saturn parking orbit or something!

Comment: The differential equation is perhaps conservation of kinetic and potential energies, latter (PE)  energy modified with an odd term. Parking orbit  has no Coreolis force.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. If you insert your parameters and $r=3$ into your differential equations, you will obtain:

- $\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d}λ} = 0$. Hence, a trajectory starting on your cycle will stay there.
- $\frac{\mathrm{d}θ}{\mathrm{d}λ} ≠ 0$. Hence, a trajectory on your cycle will not converge to a fixed point (on the cycle), but forever moves around the cycle.

Therefore, you have a limit cycle.

Comment: Except that the equations yield $r'>0$ for every $r\ne3$, hence **not** the desired trajectories.

Comment: Just one more doubt, what can I say about the stability of this cycle?

Comment: @HerrSchrödinger: From your phase-space diagram, it seems to be a saddle. Otherwise, refer to [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2642110/can-i-say-this-is-a-limit-cycle/2642183#comment5456613_2642110).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Usually limit cycle is classified by the type of fixed point of Poincaré map associated with this limit cycle. Looking at picture I'd say it's more of a saddle-node than a saddle. But I'm just nitpicking, and if Did's comment is true the picture is not relevant to the system.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft What about the fixed point criterium, wich says that there cannot exist closed orbits in a region that there is not fixed points inside it? There's no fixed point in this system.

Comment: @HerrSchrödinger: This only applies to continuous dynamics. Yours has a discontinuity at the origin, which sort-of replaces the fixed point.